# Can I make two (or more) substitions in a parameter at once?

Tags: bash, shell, replace

I want to replace each `@` and `.` by `\@` and `\.` respectively. Right now I'm solving this using the following:

```
str="@foo.bar.baz"
str=${str//"."/"\."}
str=${str/"@"/"\@"}
echo $str
```

Can I shorten this?

Comment: This immediately raises the question, *why* do you (think that you) need to do this?

Comment: I'm getting the original str from a database and need to use it like I described in the OP in some daemon configuration. Anything wrong with this?

Comment: Note that the more verbose code is also the more efficient code here.

Comment: Is there a reason that you replace all `.` but only the first `@`, contrary to your description?  Or is the single `/` a typo in the second substitution?

Comment: The string always begin with `@` so that's why I used only one `/`.

Comment: Why shorten it at all? You already have a very efficient use of *parameter expansion with substring removal* **without** spawning any additional *subshells* by calling external shell utilities. If you *pipe* to a utility like `sed` you are spawning **two** subshells, one for the pipe and the second for `sed`. Your call, but I like what you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sed`:

```
echo "@foo.bar.baz"|sed 's/[@.]/\\&/g'
```

Comment: Works, but it's *much* slower than the three-line formulation given by the OP.

Comment: This is certainly *shorter* as requested, but you really ought to point out the drawbacks (assuming it's not a code-golf question).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy It depends on the input string length, for a shorter strings bash will be faster, for a really long strings, `sed` will actually be faster.

Comment: @zeppelin, sure, but I'd be... surprised... to see a string that long on one line.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy well, I assume that this is just an example, and the real string will come from some other source, so we can only speculate on how lengthy would it be.

Comment: Granted, but the comments (that it's intended to be used in generating a configuration file) certainly *hint* at the length in the question being representative.

Comment: The lenght is not that long, it will always be a domain name begining with a '@'.